# Are named accessor properties only just about getters and setters

Tags: javascript, encapsulation

An accessor property associates a key value with one or two accessor functions, and a set of Boolean attributes. The accessor functions are used to store or retrieve an ECMAScript language value that is associated with the property.

The above is from ecmascript specification 6th edition.

Since everything in javascript are objects, and all javascript properties are named data properties (Ndps) ( to the best of my knowledge ) ... And named accessor properties (Naps) as Getters and Setters are there more to Naps than getters and setters. And the retrieval of a Ndp does it come straight from the underneath js engine like v8 or there more about its implementation on the higher level?

Example code:

```
var stuff = { 'stuff1': 1, 'stuff2': 2 }    // stuff as an Object

stuff.stuff1 // returns 1

Object.defineProperty(stuff, 'stuff3', {
    // defining stuff3's property attributes
    get: function() { return 'Hey! This is from the getter function'}
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
})

stuff.stuff1 // returns but how does it

stuff.stuff3 // returns and i know how because it was defined.
```

Is there any other implementation of `stuff`'s operation?

Please other reference materials or links should be noted.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm a JavaScript n00b, but I find it hard to understand what your actual question is.

Comment: Okay, i know stuff3 would return the string - 'Hey! This from ... ' because i defined it, but the other properties are they just going to do a name lookup like the __lookupGetter__ internal property of stuff3 ?

Comment: `var stuff = { 'stuff1': 1, 'stuff2': 2 } ` is equivalent to `Object {stuff1: 1, stuff2: 2}` so `stuff.stuff1` should return something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really anything you can do with a property except GET it or SET it, because that's how stuff works (pardon the pun).  Accessor functions provide means of doing so, but more importantly they provide you with a means of controlling **how** this is done. A GET function might require that you're logged in, or have certain access rights, for example. A SET function might prevent you from setting negative values, or only allow logged in users to use it, log the transaction to file etc.

Answer (score 1):

While the question is vague, I'll first sum it up as I understand it, and then answer it.

> Do basic properties, such as `{a: 1}.a` have a descriptor or similar inner mechanics to `Object.defineProperty(obj, 'a', {get: function() { return 1 }});`?

---

In V8, yes. Basic properties have a descriptor equivalent to `{writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true}`.

```
$ node
> var obj1 = {a: 1}
undefined
> Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj1, 'a')
{ value: 1, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true }
```

---

The ECMAScript standard talks about descriptors for specific parts of the standard language. At least in EC5 [section 8.10](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.10):

> The Property Descriptor type is used to explain the manipulation and reification of named property attributes. Values of the Property Descriptor type are records composed of named fields where each field’s name is an attribute name and its value is a corresponding attribute value as specified in 8.6.1.

And [section 8.6.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.1) states:

> Attributes are used in this specification to define and explain the state of named properties.

This pretty much confirms descriptors are something that reside outside just the `Object.defineProperty` function, and are central to the definition of access to properties.

I would tend to believe the actual location *in memory* of the stored value  - regular vs. explicitly `Object.defineProperty`'d - is implementation specific (i.e. *from where* it's actually pulling the value isn't covered in the spec).